# I use Microsoft Ergonomic keyboard with my Mac mini . It drops selected letters - capital W, U, P. - swapped keyboards - same problem please advise

Tags: keyboard, mac-mini

I have successfully used my Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 (wired) with my Mac mini.

Recently it stopped giving me anything when I asked for a capital W - which is a pain in the ass for a guy named Wayne.

Now it has spread to other keys.  So I switched to another keyboard (two actually- one of which was an apple keyboard) and I'll be damned if they doesn't produce the exact same errors - dead keys.

How can that be?
I'm not smart enough apparently.
Please advise

Comment: Two keyboards with same faults - possible but perhaps it isthe classic operator error, are you hitting the keys properly?

Comment: Sounds like you've installed some sort of key re-mapping software.